# is there any way to check internet connection fast?

Tags: android, internet-connection

i need to check internet connection with in fraction of seconds. currently i am using this code for checking internet connection but it is taking time to check internet connection. here i am using http request and response, i send one request with some website like google, after that only i got response. is it possible to get the connection while sending request. i need to check within seconds please help me

```
try {
            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }

            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)}  catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
```

thankyou

Comment: You are on the wrong track. Suggesting you to check existing threads on Stackoverflow for the same.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4239019/964741

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy  hi previously i have used this method only isNetworkAvailable(), i think this is for only network checking i need to check internet connection

Comment: @PareshMayani could you please tell me the correct way for checking internet i need to check within seconds help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

```
    private ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    private NetworkInfo activeNetwork;

    conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
// Do your task 
}
```

Comment: hi previously i have used this method only isNetworkAvailable(), i think this is for only network checking i need to check internet connection

Comment: No. Its also checks internet connection is available or not.its working in my code.Try it..

Comment: ok if it is normal internet as well as  wifi, is it working or not?

Comment: Yes its working for both..I'm using it in both condition data plan and wi-fi.I think you haven't tried it.Be sure before commenting from next time

Comment: hi i tried your code. i have error return type for the method is missing. could you please tell me what is that error

Comment: Post complete code and logcat also

Comment: hi it is working thank you so much but i have doubt. if internet sometimes get slow, at the time what will happen about checking internet connection

Comment: I think in that case you will get time out exception..Upvote and accept my answer as its working now...

Comment: could you please tell me what is get time out exception how can i implement that in this function

Comment: In the if condition you will start your asynctask for performing network operation (Your above code).in the catch block you can handle this condition

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you should give permission in manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: hi previously i have used this method only isNetworkAvailable(), i think this is for only network checking i need to check internet connection